# What is the best version of Hyperledger to use with Ethereum

Tags: hyperledger

We are considering the use of Hyperledger but not sure which "version" to use. We are considering either Fabric or Besu, depending on which solution will give us the most robust functionality with the ability to interact with Ethereum Main Net.

1. We know that Besu can be used to achieve our goal, but we will lose much of the functionality that Fabric offers. Is there a current module in Fabric that will interact with the Ethereum Main Net?
2. How difficult would it be to custom-code a solution in Hyperledger Fabric that could interact with Ethereum Main Net?
3. In either scenario, will there be an impact when ETH 2.0 is fully deployed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hyperledger Besu is just an Ethereum client implementation while Hyperledger Fabric is a completely different technology thus Besu may interact with Ethereum mainnet directly while for Fabric you will have to build some kind of bridging layer. Although it all depends on what your aim actually is - what kind of network you want to build, what are your performance requirements, potential network participants, algorithm, consensus, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I agree with you comments but I am hoping for more details. Given that both can integrate with Ethereum Main Net, which Hyperledger version is more robust and scaleable?

Comment: Hyperledger Fabric is definitely more scalable but it is strictly a permissioned private blockchain.